# Efficiently finding the slope of a line

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, linear-regression, gesture

I have a series of `(x,y)` data points: perhaps the location of an object in a video, or the position of a user's finger on a touch screen. I need to determine whether this object/touch/etc was moving in an approximately straight line, and which direction (angle, slope, or any other representation works).

My first thought was to do a linear regression for `x` in terms of `t` (the index of the sample), and another for `y` in terms of `t`, to get the slope, then use the correlation coefficients to determine how linear the data is. But this needs to run continuously on embedded hardware, and those calculations are fairly expensive.

Are there any shortcuts that I can take, given that the `t` axis is pretty much irrelevant? A linear regression for `y` in terms of `x`, for example, would be more efficient, but it would run into problems with vertical and near-vertical lines.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought for a cheap test would be to calculate the angle (relative to the X axis) of the segment between every pair of successive points, and call it not-a-line if they differ by more than an allowable error.

This would allow gentle curves to pass the test, so maybe it's better to compare the new slope to a low-pass filtered version of the old one.

Comment: Excellent thought! Ty!

Comment: Or perhaps take the mean angle of all pairs, then compare each angle to that mean? Less efficient than your proposal, but still better than multiple regressions and Pearson calculations

Comment: A mean could work. And it's not expensive if you keep a running total and count.  An advantage of a digital low pass filter is that you can adjust it to give more or less weight to the early points - you can tune for "must be in the same direction we started" vs "must be locally straight".

Answer (score 0):

Find the equation of line between the starting and ending point. Now calculate the perpendicular distance from each point towards this line. If the perpendicular distance of each lies within a tolerance value, then you can consider it as a straight line.